# How can I debug-step-through this .NET BCL code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, debugging, debug-symbols

The following method exists in the dll `System.Web.Security`

```
Dll: System.Web.Security 
File:  CookielessHelper.cs
Method: 

    // This function is called for all requests -- it must be performant.
    //    In the common case (i.e. value not present in the URI, it must not
    //    look at the headers collection
    internal void RemoveCookielessValuesFromPath() 
    { ... }
```

What steps are required for me to put a breakpoint in this method so I can figure some stuff out?

I've also got ReSharper 7 installed.

I've tried a few things but can't figure out how to do this. The closest I've got is to step through some ASP.NET MVC code, but not some of the more core stuff, like this.

Note: This question is related/inspired by [this previously asked SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089745/possible-bug-with-asp-net-mvc-3-routing).

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio includes a facility to debug into the framework.  This article describes how.

https://web.archive.org/web/20160219220557/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx

Comment: If i get stuck following that blog, can I please add my troubles to the OP for extra help?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions have been moved to Microsoft Docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-dotnet-framework-source?view=vs-2017