# Cannot disable ASP.NET cookieless mode

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm trying to find out why `UrlHelper.RouteUrl` returns me cookieless URLs that start with `/(F(`. This only seems to happen for Bing requests (`Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)`).

I already disabled cookieless mode 3 times:

```
<authentication mode="None">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>

<anonymousIdentification enabled="true" cookieless="UseCookies" />

<sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" />
```

I also added the following assertion:

```
if (url.StartsWith("/(F(", StringComparison.Ordinal))
    throw new Exception(
        FormsAuthentication.CookieMode + " " +
        FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported + " " +
        HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Cookies);
```

This throws in case of bing bot. But it claims that `CookieMode == UseCookies && CookiesSupported == true && Browser.Cookies == true`. This means that the config setting took, as well as that ASP.NET thinks that Bing bot *does* support cookies. There should be no reason whatsoever to prepend this cookieless string to the URL.

I cannot reproduce it locally on Windows 7 .NET 4.7. The production server runs Server 2008 R2 with .NET 4.7.

I tried really hard disabling this nasty feature. How can I escape this madness?

---

Update: The `F` seems to mean that the forms authentication feature is responsible. But clearly it is disabled in the web.config?! I'm not using it in any way as far as I know (might be a wrong assumption).

Also, I tested the "app path modifier" value which is being used by MVC:

```
var x =
(string)typeof(HttpResponse)
.GetField("_appPathModifier", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
.GetValue(HttpContext.Current.Response);
```

I added this value to the assert and indeed the nasty `/(F(` string is present here. I have no idea how it comes to be that the .NET Framework sets this value.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your server is currently giving out those URLs and they’re not just in Bing’s list of URLs to check?

Comment: Yes. The assert is directly after `Url.RouteUrl` and tests the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Because before that, the value of SessionId has been removed (CookielessHelper.RemoveCookielessValuesFromPath) from url path.

HttpContext's Init method process that.

```
private void Init(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
{
    this._request = request;
    this._response = response;
    this._utcTimestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
    this._principalContainer = this;
    if (this._wr is IIS7WorkerRequest)
    {
        this._isIntegratedPipeline = true;
    }
    if (!(this._wr is StateHttpWorkerRequest))
    {
        this.CookielessHelper.RemoveCookielessValuesFromPath();
    }
    // other codes ...
}
```

Please Ref [Possible Bug With ASP.NET MVC 3 Routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089745/possible-bug-with-asp-net-mvc-3-routing)

I will check Response._appPathModifier value at Application_BeginRequest event,

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //到這時，Url已被改成沒包含SessionId
    //但它的值會放在 Response._appPathModifier 變數之中
    var appPathModifierFieldInfo = Context.Response.GetType().GetField("_appPathModifier",
                 BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var appPathModifier = appPathModifierFieldInfo.GetValue(Context.Response);
    if (appPathModifier != null)
    {
        //url 中有 SessionId
        throw new HttpException(404, "Not found");
    }
}
```