# how to turn off automatic routing in URL for .NET mvc application

Tags: .net, url, routes

My web application is based on .NET ASP MVC technology.

https://danswebsite.com/(D(anythingBlahBlahBlah))/en/Auths/AuthList

has the same result as

https://danswebsite.com/en/Auths/AuthList

which is the original URL.

I want to remove this automatic routing feature. I removed resolveUrl in the javascript files in my code base. But it still has this automatic routing feature as long as the first letter is from A to Z, in the example above, it is the letter D.

In global.asax.cs,

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
  
    routes.MapRoute("l10n", "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
                    new { lang = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    routes.MapRoute("err", "{controller}/{action}/{exception}", 
                    new { controller = "Errors", action = "ApplicationError" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new string[] { "DansWebSite.Mvc.Controllers" } 
    );
}
```

Could you help me to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Dan

Comment: Can you show your routing configuration?

Comment: I put the code of registering routes in the global.asax.cs.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017, I created a sample project using MVC. It behaves the same way!        http://localhost:55081/Home/(A(xxxx))/Contact works, but it should not!

Comment: It surprises me as well. I am not behind my PC, but, I'll give it a try

Comment: Interresting, it works different for `(X(foo))` and `(x(foo))`. Seems to be some URL formatiing or such...

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/1749701.aspx?Session+ID+in+URL

Comment: That is interresting...  altough I am still curious what it actually is. If you know, please post it as answer.

Comment: Next to that, I am considering to place a bounty on this question to let it gain more attention

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089745/possible-bug-with-asp-net-mvc-3-routing?rq=1

Comment: The above link gives more details. There seems no way to get rid of it.